# Parity -- How to delete DB and resync it?

Tags: parity

```
[master][~/parity/target/release]$ ./parity import /tmp/avatar.rlp
```

**Error Output:** Database was created with newer client version. Upgrade your client or delete DB and resync.

I could not understand:
[Q]How could I delete the DB or resync it?, I couldn't find where the DB is stored?

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check ~/.parity

Don't forget to backup your ~/.parity/keys

Comment: => Could I clean complete "~/.parity" folder?

Comment: Yeah, backup keys if you need them

Answer (score 7):

Parity [developer @5chdn said to use](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6402#issuecomment-332835951):

```
parity --light db kill
```

Answer (score 3):

To be precise:

`parity db kill —config /path/to/your/toml file`

This helps if you have multiple chains or private chains.

Answer (score 2):

The database location seems to have moved since [Igor's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9170/15903).

I found it at:

```
~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db
```

Close parity before deleting this directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
parity db kill
```

is nothing, it cannot remove the db data, just remove '.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d', it will clean the world

Comment: On latest version `./openethereum db kill` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

And you have to delete the user_default file also.If its still there after deleting this db folder still there will be the same error