# How to reset private blockchain (Parity) and delete contracts?

Tags: parity, private-blockchain, contract-deployment, dapps

I have a private blockchain where I'm testing a contract and I want to re-deploy a very-slightly modified version.  I need to delete the old one first.  I control all of the nodes, so I can do this.

But I don't know how?

I tried deleting the ~/.parity/chains config dapps directories, but the contract is still out there.

Do I have to delete these directories on every node?  Do I have to delete the "network" directory also?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but just so you know you can redeploy the modified contract and just use the address for the new contract instead.  Probably much easier than constantly restarting a new private chain.

Comment: @jojeyh Thank you but I don't know anything about a contract address.  This contract is accessible via its own RPC port, so I can only have one at a time.

Comment: @jojeyh I should say that that was good info.  Just not really specific to this question. :)

Comment: can the contract send internal transactions?

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake I'm sorry but I don't know.  I don't know much about writing contracts and I don't know what this one is all about.  I just want to get rid of it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Stop all nodes
2. Delete blockcahin folder on every node
3. Recreate your blockchain from genesis at one node
4. Start this node
5. Connect other nodes to it

Did not tried, do not have oportunity now:( Try if this can help

Comment: Please be more specific.  As you see in my original question, "I tried deleting the ~/.parity/chains config dapps directories, but the contract is still out there."

Comment: Backup ~/.parity/keys (just copy somewhere). Remove ~/.parity. Create ~/.parity. Restore keys

Comment: Take a look at this too https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9163/parity-how-to-delete-db-and-resync-it

Comment: That seems to be effectively the same as what I write in my first comment.  But in that case, the contract is not deleted.

Comment: Did you try to run parity as single node? I supose that your node, where you removed bolckchain db, connects to other nodes and takes blockchain from them. Another suggestion: check the blockchain directory path - take a look at https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6634

Comment: You are probably right.  I must have made a mistake and possibly didn't delete the data from all nodes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The contract cannot be "out there" if all nodes on your private network delete all their data. So, as previously described by Alexey Barsuk, you just need to stop all nodes and then delete all their blockdata. Do not forget to backup your keys.

Comment: You and Alexey are probably right.  I must have made a mistake and possibly didn't delete the data from all nodes.  Thank you.